# Phonegap ui retrieved from cloud

Tags: user-interface, cordova, cloud

I have an enquiry regarding ui that's retrieved from cloud for a phonegap app. Till to date, I have been using the basics, html/js/css to build the app. However, recently, I decided to move all of the coding to cloud, which is then fetched as according to the request that's sent to the server. Thus, the ui coding (most of it) is not in the app itself, its in the cloud. Am I violating any android/ios ui guidelines. Will this practice lead to rejection in playstore or itunes? As such, there is only one html page in the app that's constantly being changed with the ui retrieved from cloud.

Answer (score 0):

**Am I violating any android/ios ui guidelines?**

Yes. It is very bad UI to let the user wait for the UI to finish loading. BTW it has no performance benefit because the UI is usually loaded from file system. Even worst, if there is no internet connection you app won't load up. For me it sounds like you are building a web app. So you should not use phonegap, make it a native web app.

If you have more questions regarding UI, please ask them here https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks @artworkad. I will be storing the html templates in localstorage which will be used when the handphone goes offline. And when UI is being loaded, the loading sign, etc will be shown. Still bad?

Comment: @shiva Why are you using phonegap at all?